# Are bombs able to blast open the Lihzahrd Temple's door?

Tags: terraria-mobile

In Terraria, I blew up the temple door with a simple Bomb. But after a few weeks, the method did not work anymore. Why was that happening? Is the bombs meant to blow up the temple door?

Comment: By "Temple" do you mean the Lihzahrd Temple in the Jungle?

Answer (score 1):

In update 1.2.8798 of Terraria, they made it to where you can't explode the Lihzahrd Temple door anymore with explosives. The explosives arn't meant to open the door anyway, though. What you are supposed to use is a key obtained from defeating Plantera. It has a 100% chance of dropping, so its normally pretty easy to get your hands on, assuming you have the means to deafeat Plantera. You can find updates to Terraria and the changes they made [here.](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Mobile_Version_history)